# Mouse wheel scrolling ignores first scroll

Tags: gnome, virtualbox, mouse

I installed Ubuntu 15.10 in a VirtualBox in Windows 7 and everything is working as expected so far apart from one little thing that drives me crazy.

It happens in gnome applications like gedit and synaptic, but doesn't happen in applications like xfce4-terminal (where I can scroll the buffer using the mouse wheel).

**The problem is** that after clicking with the left mouse button in the gnome application, **the first scroll wheel up / down activation is lost** and only from the second up / down activation on scrolling actually happens. This feels like scrolling is not reliable and exact so I would really like to get rid of it.

I don't think using VirtualBox is the problem since it doesn't happen in xfce4-terminal, and I configured the mouse to emulate a PS/2 mouse, not a touchpad. However I think this behaviour of gnome may be due to some default setting which is thought of being a good default for touchpads to prevent unintended scrolling or something like that.

I didn't find any option to change this behaviour in the ubuntu mouse settings or the xfce4 mouse settings, and I didn't find anything useful when searching for options in gconf-editor or dconf-editor.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by using imwheel, just put this into `~/.imwheelrc`

```
".*"
Control_L, Up,   Control_L|Button4
Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
Shift_L,   Up,   Shift_L|Button4
Shift_L,   Down, Shift_L|Button5
```

and run `imwheel -b "45"`.

PS: It doesn't change the scrolling speed of any application.

Comment: just starting up `imwheel` solved the problem with no configuration at all (on Ubuntu 22)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug happens when using Gnome+Xorg. I have the same problem in gnome 3.32 Arch running natively.

For the time being you can switch to wayland to solve the problem.

I heard that libinput may be the cause but after switching to evdev  the problem was still there.

Comment: I switched to wayland and the problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

There is another workaround:

First, add this line to your .bashrc/.zshrc

```
export GDK_CORE_DEVICE_EVENTS=1
```

Then add this launch parameter

```
--disable-high-precision-scrolling
```

to all chromium based applications i.e. all electron applications

Answer (score 0):

It is still an unsolved bug, but there is a solution... English is not my first language but I will try my best.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/IMWheel

1. First install imwheel, depending on your distro the installation will be different, for ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install imwheel
```

2. On your home directory create an .imwheelrc file with the following content, this is for the back and forth buttons of your mouse:

```
".*"
None, Thumb1, Alt_L|Left
None, Thumb2, Alt_L|Right
```

3. Then, you need to start imwheel:

```
imwheel
```

4. For imwheel to run at startup, create a startup.sh script in /etc/profile.d/ with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
imwheel
```

Optional, (I haven't tried this yet), you can start or stop imwheel (`killall imwheel`) when you connect or disconnect your mouse:
[Running the script when it detects I/O](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844646/running-the-script-when-it-detects-i-o)