# Running the script when it detects I/O

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, mouse, bluetooth

I have bluetooth mouse xinput setting script to run whenever i have connect the mouse. Currently I'm simply alias the short key as 'bm' for that bash file execution but I want to know if there is automatic way to execute the bash file or alias command whenever it detects the mouse connection.

Thank in advance!

ubuntu 16.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a .[rules](https://wiki.debian.org/udev) file.

First, find out the `ID_VENDOR_ID` and the `ID_MODEL_ID` of your mouse. Disconnect the mouse, run this command and connect the mouse (the `|grep ID` part is only to filter information that you don't need).

```
udevadm monitor --property|grep ID
```

Lets say that you get these values:

```
ID_VENDOR_ID=0a12
ID_MODEL_ID=0001
```

Now create a file in the rules folder (96 is the priority of the rule):

```
sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/96-myusb.rules
```

Add these two lines using your values for the `ID_VENDOR_ID` and `ID_MODEL_ID`. If you don't want to do anything when you remove it, don't include the second line.

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="0a12", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="0001",RUN+="/usr/local/bin/myusb-add.sh"

ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="0a12",ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="0001",RUN+="/usr/local/bin/myusb-remove.sh"
```

You can test that it works creating the two scripts:

```
$ sudo gedit /usr/local/bin/myusb-add.sh
```

Add something like this (change `add` to `remove` in the other one):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "added" >> /tmp/myusb.log
```

Finally, tail the file with `tail -f /tmp/myusb.log` and connect/disconnect your mouse. You should see that the text gets added to the file.

Comment: it works!! awesome!! thank you for such a detail step by step instruction with description.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to use polling approach, to continuously read output of `xinput --list --name-only` and figure out if the name of your mouse is there or not, and if it is - run the script. This would be something like this:

```
while true; do
    if xinput --list --name-only | grep -q -i 'Mouse Name' ; 
    then 
        echo "yes" # this is where you run script
        break # exit the loop after running the script.   
    fi 
done
```

In this case we exit loop as soon as the mouse is there. However you probably want this to be continuous so that you can connect and disconnect  the mouse. Instead of `break`, I'd use another `while` loop there, that does the opposite - waits for mouse name to disappear. Body of that while loop can be just this - `true` or `:`.