# how to set rule only for usb flash drives in rules.d

Tags: usb, permissions, users, udev

Simple question: how to add rule for usb flash drives only in `/lib/udev/rules.d/` catalog?

For e.g. if I want to allow only usb flash drives for my PC to be inserted. Or allow only my flash drive. Is there any device type/grupot for that purpose?

Could anybody provide some example for noob, please? I hope it is easy to solve :)

Comment: Here few related: [Only use Mass Storage devices on a selected USB port - how?](https://askubuntu.com/q/531445/26246) ; [How to execute C++ program whenever a USB flash drive is inserted](https://askubuntu.com/q/625243/26246) ; [udev rules to allow only one vendor and model USB drive but no others](https://askubuntu.com/q/626744/26246).  those have answer for your example cases.

Comment: You may use advanced search to get more examples, eg: [`[udev][usb]`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/udev+usb) for all topic tagged with `udev` & `usb`.

Answer (score 2):

I answered a similar question with an example a while ago:

[Running the script when it detects I/O](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844646/running-the-script-when-it-detects-i-o/844698#844698)

Use this command,

```
udevadm monitor --property
```

Insert the USB and check a property that is common to the devices that you want to use, e.g:

```
ID_TYPE=disk
ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage
```

Then create your rule

```
sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/96-myusb.rules
```

with those values in

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ENV{ID_TYPE}=="disk", ENV{ID_USB_DRIVER}=="usb-storage",RUN+="/usr/local/bin/myusb-add.sh"

ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ENV{ID_TYPE}=="disk",ENV{ID_USB_DRIVER}=="usb-storage",RUN+="/usr/local/bin/myusb-remove.sh"
```

The rules file will only affect those devices that match the `ENV{ID_TYPE}` and `ENV{ID_USB_DRIVER}`. It will not affect any other device. If you want to restrict the rest of devices, maybe you can create a rule that matches the rest of devices and does nothing in the `RUN`.

If you want to run the action only when a certain usb device is connected to an specific USB port, try adding ENV{DEVPATH}="yourUSBPATH" to the rules file. Substitute yourUSBPATH for the path that `udevadm monitor --property` reports when you connect the device to the port that you want to use. I haven't tested this but I think it's a logical approach.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. But I have this `ID_TYPE = scsi` after usb flash drive insertion.  So, as a next step I have to write some script in `/usr/local/bin/` folder to restrict access for any other usb device, am I rigth?

Comment: @mr.boris I have edited the answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: I've added `/etc/udev/rules.d/96-myusb.rules` file with this rule `ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ENV{ID_TYPE}=="disk", ENV{ID_USB_DRIVER}=="usb-storage",RUN+=""` but it doesn't work. I still able to insert any usb device, so no changes. Why such simple thing is so complicated and nobody can help even linux pros???

Comment: @mr.boris have you replaced ID_TYPE and ID_USB_DRIVER with the values that you get in udevadm? Did you add a script to run after the RUN+?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood you. I left  **RUN** empty because I thought that it should be empty to restrict the rest of devices as you wrote above. Yes, I have replaced it as in my previous comment: **ID_TYPE=disk** and **ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage**. Seems that I have to assign some bash command for my rule now (as you wrote before: `RUN+="/usr/local/bin/myusb-add.sh"`). Could you give me some advice what should I have in the `myusb-add.sh` script, please? Should it unmount usb port on udevadm event and how? How can I specify only one required usb port in the bash script?

Comment: @mr.boris Yes, you have to create a script that performs the action you want when the USB is inserted. Have a look at the links posted by user.dz. There seem to be a lot of good infor in them.

Comment: I've already looked at links posted by **user.dz** but there's nothing about bash script that performs the main job (forbid device on specified usb port). Now I realized that udev part (device recognition) is the lesser of problems because nobody can answer how to implement a bash script since `ignore_device` method was removed with udev release 148. Based upon posts of users it is a pain and there is no code example how to do it and everybody redirects for searcing somewhere for something. In any case, thanks for the help.

Comment: @rm.boris I edited the answer with what I would do but I haven't tested it. good luck.